# How to add bootstrap and jquery in rails using import map?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rails7

I'm setup rails 7 app. And i wan't to add bootstrap and jquery using import map. I'll try but didn't work. I follow this step if i made any mistake please correct.

1. rails new demo
2. bundle install
3. create demo controller with index and add some bootstrap code.
4. Then i run this command bin/importmap pin bootstrap

So. in Import map added this two line
pin "bootstrap", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js"
pin "@popperjs/core", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@popperjs/core@2.11.5/lib/index.js"

If i already pin bootstrap in importmap.rb file. Why it's not working or i missing some configration.

Thanks for replay.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have following files with corresponding content:

```scss
// app/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss

@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons';
```

```json
# package.json

{
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "sass": "^1.50.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
  }
}
```

```js
# app/javascript/application.js

import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"
```

```rb
# config/importmap.rb

pin "bootstrap", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js"
```

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.{erb|slim|haml}

<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
  <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
</head>
```

And run server with `bin/dev` command

To install `JQuery` run `bin/importmap pin jquery` command and import it in `application.js` file

```js
# app/javascript/application.js

import { $, jQuery } from 'jquery'

// export for others scripts to use
window.$ = $
window.jQuery = jQuery
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay. But when I create a new app package.json + application.bootstrap.scss file is not created. Other config are fine.

Comment: I try with bin command but didn't work. I think i missed some config.

Comment: Can you try to run `rails css:install:bootstrap`?. It will add missing files. Also try to rebuild css `rails css:build`

Comment: I'll try but didn't work. When I try to build command it's show me an error like Don't know how to build task 'css:install:bootstrap' (See the list of available tasks with `rails --tasks`). But I'll try to fix this issue. Thaks for help.